# Todos os dados de uma consulta em um array

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso que todos os dados de um select esteja em um formato de array. Todas as formas que já tentei retornam apenas o último dado da tabela. Como devo proceder ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Termos";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

   $palavras = "array(" . $row['Descricao']. ")" ;

    }
}
```

Se no banco de dados tivesse as palavras VIDA, TESTE E SONHO, gostaria de um retorno exatamente assim>

**$palavras = array("vida", "teste", "sonho");**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ver isso resolve seu problema

```
    $itens= [];
    $sql = "SELECT nome
            FROM termos";

    $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($termo);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        array_push($itens, $termo);
    }
    return $itens;
```

Comment: Qual erro está aparecendo?

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado amigo, o erro era da minha parte aqui, perfeito!

Comment: Sucesso, fico feliz em ajuda-lo